Why my Azure B2C signIn/signUp pages have only half of words translated?
I'm doing a basic SignIn / SignUp userFlow,
I'm trying to have correct translations but when i run my userFlow with ui_locales set this is my result:

Only half of my sign in page is translated, and for any languages,
even with my default one "fr" and default translation JSONs.
Any ideas ?
I tried with my navigator in french too, and without auto-translators, i still have this pb

It's probably not the desired solution, but I downloaded the "defaults (fr)" translations and change all the Override values from false to true. Then I uploaded my modified JSON.
It works, but I still don't get why my default fr translations were not set...
